# combine two lists of different case class types

Tags: scala

Combine two case class lists in to merged case class list

```
case class emp(emp_id:Integer,emp_name:String)
case class manager(manger_id:Integer,manager_name :String,emp_id:Integer)

case class combined(emp_id:Integer,emp_name :String,
manager_id:Integer,manager_name :String)

val list1:List[emp]= List((1,"emp1"),(2,"emp2")
val list2:List[manager]= List((101,"mgr1",1)(103,"mgr3",1))
```

expected output

```
 val list3 = List(

(1,"emp1",101,"mgr1"),
(1,"emp1",103,"mgr3"),
(2,"emp2",null,null))
```

Comment: If you add a `manager(104,"mgr4",4)`, would that create the output `combined(null,null,104,"mgr4")` or would that be ignored in the output? Also, why use `null`? Wouldn't `Option` be better?

Comment: manager case class should have valid emp id.So the case of emp id not being part of List1 does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on. If your data is already sorted by `emp_id and you have the same amount of managers as employees you can go with:

```
list1.zip(list2).map { case (e, m) => 
 combined(e.emp_id, e.emp_name, m.manager_id, m.manager_name)
}
```

However, I suppose is not the case in a real-life scenario, where you need to match. Since the managers have an `emp_id` you can first run a `groupBy` on managers and then iterate over the employees to enrich them with manager input.

```
val grouped: Map[Int, manager] =  list2.groupBy(_.emp_id)

list1.map { e => 

 val manager_id = grouped.get(e.emp_id).flatMap (l => 
  Try{l(0)}.toOption.map(_.manager_id)).getOrElse("null")

 val manager_name = grouped.get(e.emp_id).flatMap (l => 
  Try{l(0)}.toOption.map(_.manager_name)).getOrElse("null")

 combined(e.emp_id, e.emp_name, manager_id, manager_name)
}
```

Did not checked the syntax, but you should get the point here.

P.S
Please use CamelCase and capital letters for classes in Scala.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea, above code works with some minor changes.But it picks only one manager matching the emp id.mgr(103,"mgr3",1) is not picked in the combined as map.get(empid) is returning only one value

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd be tempted to tackle it.

```scala
// types
case class Emp(emp_id:Int, emp_name:String)
case class Manager(manager_id:Int, manager_name:String, emp_id:Int)

case class Combined(emp_id       :Int
                   ,emp_name     :String
                   ,manager_id   :Option[Int]
                   ,manager_name :String)

// input data
val emps :List[Emp]     = List(Emp(1,"emp1"),Emp(2,"emp2"))
val mgrs :List[Manager] = List(Manager(101,"mgr1",1),Manager(103,"mgr3",1))

// lookup Emp name by ID
val empName = emps.groupMapReduce(_.emp_id)(_.emp_name)(_+_)

mgrs.map(mgr => Combined(mgr.emp_id
                        ,empName(mgr.emp_id)
                        ,Some(mgr.manager_id)
                        ,mgr.manager_name)
        ) ++ empName.keySet
                    .diff(mgrs.map(_.emp_id).toSet)
                    .map(id => Combined(id, empName(id), None, ""))

//res0: List[Combined] = List(Combined(1, "emp1", Some(101), "mgr1")
//                           ,Combined(1, "emp1", Some(103), "mgr3")
//                           ,Combined(2, "emp2", None,      ""))
```

I used `Option[Int]` and empty string `""` to replace `null`, which Scala style tries to avoid.